# Processing new and old variable in Firebird triggers

Tags: triggers, firebird

This is my pseudocode to access the new and old variable in a Firebird trigger.

```
create trigger my_trigger for cards
  before insert or update
as
  declare var_reccord cards;
begin
    if (inserting) then
    begin
        var_reccord = new;
    end
    else
    begin
        var_reccord = old;
    end

    -- USE var_reccord
end
```

But this does not work for me. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you want to use something like Oracle's `%ROWTYPE` but unfortunately current Firebird versions do not support that.

The `old` and `new` context variables allow access to columns, not to the entire row. In other words, you must use them like `old.columnName`. See the [documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-triggers.html#fblangref25-psql-oldnew) for more info.

For example, if table `cards` has a field `foo` then you could use it like

```
create trigger my_trigger for cards
  before insert or update
as
  declare var_foo TYPE OF COLUMN cards.foo;
begin
    if (inserting) then
    begin
        var_foo = new.foo;
    end
    else
    begin
        var_foo = old.foo;
    end

    -- USE var_foo
end
```